# Create a variable to save all data from user input

Tags: python

I am writing a small console program to get values from user and iterate over them and show it back to the user. But I should keep all the values which I am getting from a user in one variable. Here is what I could create:

```
def get_options():
    print('============= Intranet App ==============')
    print('Please, choose the activity. Enter the corresponding number.')
    print('1. Create user')
    print('2. Notify users')
    print('3. Quit app')

    a = int(input('Option: '))

    all_users = []
    print('In variable you have these values', all_users)
    while True:
        if a == 1:
            print('Please enter the user type. (i.e., student, lecturer, management)')
            global user_type
            user_type = input('Enter user roles:')
            user_list = user_type.split()

        if user_type:
            print('Exiting program..')
            get_options()
        print(user_type, 'is created')
        all_users += user_list
        print(all_users)
```

But when new recursion starts values from `all_users` disappear. What can I do to keep all values in one variable and these values never should be deleted?

Comment: define all_users =[] outside of get_options() function because  when get_options called recursively, it creates new instance of all_users everytime.

Comment: but variable all_user will become global so I don't know how to call it inside the recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a keyword argument and pass the list to the layers of recursion below, you can persist the `all_users` list.

```
def get_options(all_users=None):
    if all_users is None:
        all_users = []
# later in the func
    get_options(all_users=all_users)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make your `all users` list global instead of local for `get_options`. define the `all_users` outside your `get_options` function.

Comment: please can you show me in the real example?  If I will declare the variable outside of recursion how then can I access that variable inside recursion?

Comment: Hey Dustin, there is something which you call LGB rule. a variable is first checked in Local scope then Global scope and finally in Built-in.